# Tracking which files are used by program

Tags: process, open-files, lsof

I am looking for a way to track which files are used by program installer(InstallAnywhere). I cannot use `lsof` because as far as I know it works on active processes and I want a tool which will work something like that:

```
Time:
--------------------------------------------------------
Tool start here:
   |-------------------------------------------|
Installer starts here:
      |-----------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also consider invoking your command under strace:

```
strace -f -e trace=file -o /path/to/logfile your_command
```

`logfile` would contain every file-related operation performed by `your_command` or its child processes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [checkinstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org) is what you want.

Comment: Please detail a bit more